# Redirect in .Net Core Application

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-core, response.redirect

im trying to do some operation .Net Core and after this operation is done, i want to redirect it to a .cshtml page. In homepage i have table, after selecting a row in the table, im sending the value of the cell with ajax.

[image: Table]

## AJAX

```
 $('#table').find('tr').click(function () {         
        var userName = $(this).find('td').text();
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Profile/printUser",
            type: 'POST',
            data: { "DisplayName": userName }
        });        
    });
```

After this part, im going to this area

## FUNCTION

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult printUser(User user)
    {
        user.DisplayName = user.DisplayName.Replace("\n", String.Empty);
        user.DisplayName = user.DisplayName.Trim(' ');
       
        User findUser = UserAdapter.GetUserByUserName(user.DisplayName);
      
        return RedirectToAction("ProfileScreen",findUser);      
    }
```

My operations are finished, i found my user. All i want to do is print this users information in cshtml. But i cant send myselft to the page. How can i redirect myself? Thanks.

## INDEX

```
 public IActionResult ProfileScreen()
    {          
        return View();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't redirect from Ajax call in the backend. Use AJAX's

```
  success: function(){ 
        windows.location.href = '/ProfileScreen'; 
    }
```

If you want to pass data back, return JSON from MVC action and your JavaScript would be:

```
$('#table').find('tr').click(function () {         
        var userName = $(this).find('td').text();
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Profile/printUser",
            type: 'POST',
            data: { "DisplayName": userName },
            success: function(data){
              window.location.href = '/ProfileScreen' + data.ID; //or whatever
            }
        });        
    });
```

Comment: Thanks alot, I suspected about ajax's success function. It solved my redirect problem, but i couldnt pass my findUser with using success(data). Something is not true in my code. Am i should use return RedirectToAction("ProfileScreen",findUser);   ? Thanks for your help

Comment: You have to return JSON from your MVC Action. Try this: `return Ok(new { ID: findUser.ID});`

Comment: Should i use JsonResult?

Comment: @Berkin JsonResult worked in previous MVC. Not sure if it's still there in .NET CORE. You can try it.

Comment: Yeah i could reach it by using this

Comment: return Json(new { displayName = findUser.DisplayName});

Comment: Thanks alot. I will put here my solution. I LOVE STACKOVERFLOW <3

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION

## FUNCTION

```
[HttpPost]
        public JsonResult printUser(User user)
        {
            user.DisplayName = user.DisplayName.Replace("\n", String.Empty);
            user.DisplayName = user.DisplayName.Trim(' ');
           
            User findUser = UserAdapter.GetUserByUserName(user.DisplayName);

            return Json(new { displayName = findUser.DisplayName});
        }
```